# AMQP protocol version mismach when running ActiveMQ and RabbitMQ in a same machine simultanueously

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, activemq-classic, amqp

I have been trying to develop a project which use both activeMQ and rabbitMQ at the same time. The dependencies which I added in pom.xml listed below:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
        <version>5.13.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Also, I run the [apache-activemq-5.13.0](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/activemq/5.13.0/apache-activemq-5.13.0-bin.zip) and [rabbitmq-server-3.5.6](https://www.rabbitmq.com/download.html) at the same time.
But unfortunately, I faced an error which is related to the AMQP and demonstrated below:

```
java.io.IOException
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:106)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:102)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:350)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:648)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:678)
    at org.hafiz.framework.common.rabbit.filter.ReceiveRabbitMessageFilter.init(ReceiveRabbitMessageFilter.java:33)
    at org.hafiz.common.filter.PrmTarrifTypeMessageFilter.init(PrmTarrifTypeMessageFilter.java:21)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4854)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5546)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1263)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1948)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:67)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:37)

    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:367)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:293)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.MalformedFrameException: AMQP protocol version mismatch; we are version 0-9-1, server sent signature 0,1,0,0
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.protocolVersionMismatch(Frame.java:174)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:111)

    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:139)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:536)
    ... 1 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hafiz.framework.common.rabbit.filter.ReceiveRabbitMessageFilter.receiveMessage(ReceiveRabbitMessageFilter.java:61)
    at org.hafiz.common.filter.PrmTarrifTypeMessageFilter$1.run(PrmTarrifTypeMessageFilter.java:29)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I will be appreciate if any one help me tackle this error.

Comment: Have you configured them to use different ports?

Comment: @Kenney I have already looked for the config file in the etc folder of the rabbitMQ installation directory. But the only file I found named "rabbitmq.config.example". So, I changed the port number in that file to 5673. However I think it is not the right file to change.

Comment: Have you seen [rabbitmq configure](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html) - seems to use environment variables. If that fails, you could change the [activemq transport configuration](http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html). Only one of them need to be changed, after all.

Comment: @Kenney Thank you for your response, I changed the RabbitMQ port just like the instructions in the link you told. Unfortunately the error has not changed yet.

Comment: @Kenney I finally succeeded tackling the problem. I don't know why but I couldn't change the RabbitMQ port. Because of that, I changed the default port of ActiveMQ instead. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is just change one of those message brokers port number. As both of them work on a same port (5672), you should just simply change the configuration of one of them.

For rabbitMQ, you can fallow the instructions which are explained [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html), just like @Kenney said it is as simple as setting an environment variable.

**Note:** Do not forget reinstalling RabbitMQ service during setting the variable.

In windows, you can do this by running commands below in the command prompt:

1. cd into the sbin folder under RabbitMQ server installation directory and run rabbitmq-service.bat remove
2. set RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT=xxxx
3. rabbitmq-service.bat install

Moreover, if it doesn't work you can simply change the default port of ActiveMQ for amqp. To do this you should look for the file name activemq.xml in the **conf** folder located in the ActiveMQ server installation directory.
I hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your invaluable answer, but just like I told @Kenney, although I have done what you suggested already, the error has not changed.

Comment: I finally succeeded in this issue by changing the default port number of ActiveMQ just like you said. thank you very much. @Reza

Answer (score -1):

Protocol AMQP works on port 5672, both the message brokers support for this protocol. Just move one of them to another machine.